# EOS Block Producer Claim Reward

Tags: nodeos, eosio-code, eosio.token, eosio.system, private-blockchain

I have followed Bios boot sequence tutorial from eosio and setup a private eos blockchain. The problem is the block producers i have created , when i tried to claim reward it shows "cannot claim rewards until the chain is activated (at least 15% of all tokens participate in voting).
Also the blockproducer havnt produced any block, all the blocks are created by eosio.Can Someone tell what i am missing for block producers to produce the blocks and claim the rewards?

Answer (score 2):

In `[producer_pay.cpp][1]`, you'll find: 
`const int64_t  min_activated_stake   = 150'000'000'0000;`
You'll want to either alter that when loading the contracts, or just issue tokens to some accounts and ensure that enough votes (150 million) have been cast to pass this threshold.

Comment: i have issued required tokens to my block producer account even after that it is'nt in the block producer schedule list. The schedule list only shows eosio and the blocks are getting signed by only eosio.

Comment: Have you issued the tokens *and* voted with them? (you'll need to delegate those tokens to a resource first as well)

Comment: Have you tried using eosio.bios action `setprods`?
https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/8c03c9132b1bf8244d6c4724f2dede4bda352e68/contracts/eosio.bios/include/eosio.bios/eosio.bios.hpp#L121-L130